# Wordpress Infinite scroll & facebook like,share box

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, facebook-likebox

I made a site http://18union.cc/, and used the infinite scroll in homepage.

When I scroll down, the facebook like&share box doesn't show up.

I have tried many methods, but it didn't work.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reinitialize the facebook script after the Ajax completes.

You can add your code between this code:

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  jQuery( ".log" ).text( "Add Facebook initialisation here." );
})
```

You should add this in your custom javaScript file.